# ssl certificate installation - wp 8.1 SL

Tags: silverlight, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, windows-phone-8.1

I've installed ssl certificate (which I downloaded from a webbrowser) via email on the device. Unfortunately, after the installation I still can't open the page in IE without warning ('It looks like the security certificate wasn't issued by a trusted certificate authority...').

I have to install my custom certificate properly, because without it I can't provide https connection between my wp 8.1 silverlight app and my web service. I tried .p7b, .peb, .cer and .cert certificates.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Untrusted certificates only work for email inboxes, not for apps. Either use HTTP or a paid cert.